# How can people from a different VLAN join another VLAN's Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, vlan

I have two VLANs:

- `uservlan`
- `servervlan` (where DC Server 2003, webserver exists).

I'm using Active Directory. Since the DC is on a different network (VLAN), how do people from `uservlan` join the Active Directory?

How do I implement this type of design?

Comment: Can I ask why your server is on a different vlan to your users? Separate VLANs would typically be used to separate a guest network or VOIP from your domain but the server and workstations would normally be on the same.

Comment: If this is a network of more than a few users, which it probably is if there's an AD Domain Controller, then this is a perfectly good design.  Network segmentation is one of the most basic levels of security controls.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a Layer 3 switch you can route the traffic between vlans by just using the switch, if you don't then you do it by using a router, either on some server/computer (you can use Windows Server with Routing and Remote Access service) or some device like Cisco router or similar, the router will have to have three network interfaces (one for one vlan, one for other and one for Internet link). This would be the simplest solution.